# Which data type to use for number 10^1000 in C?

Tags: c

I was working on a question using C language. The problem was "to determine whether a number n is divisible by 15 or not". The range of `n` was [1 to 10<sup>1000</sup>]. There is no data type in C which can do the needful, so what should I do ?

Comment: Apparently, the range was picked to not fit in any C standard type so the solution is expected to be implemented in another fashion.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is no datatype built in to handle that and you don't need one to detect whether a number is divisible by `15` or not. Just get those digits in a string (NUL terminated `char` array in [c](/questions/tagged/c)) and check whether the last digit (least significant digit) is `5` or `0` and also check whether the digit sum of those digits, which constitute the number, (it would be as per your need - roughly at max `10001` digits) is divisible by `3` or not. If both conditions are satisfied which  is the criteria to be divisible by `15`(as the prime factors of `15` is `3` and `5` which dictates a number divisible by `15` should be divisible by `3` and `5` both), it is divisible by `15`.

Answer (score 2):

> "to determine whether a number n is divisible by 15 or not"

Is is not too hard to make this more general and answer the question:

> "to determine whether a number N is divisible by M or not"

Encode the large integer `N` as a *string* of decimal digits.  Perform modulo math (`%`) on each digit, scaling the prior result by 10. Then check if the final result is 0.

```
y = (y * 10 + digit) % m;
```

Simple function call

```
unsigned string_mod(const char *s, unsigned m) {
  unsigned y = 0;
  while (*s) {
    unsigned digit = (unsigned) (*s++ - '0');
    y = (y * 10 + digit) % m;
  }
  return y;
}
```

---

Test code

```
void test(const char *s, unsigned m) {
  printf("%s is%s divisible by %u\n",
      s, string_mod(s,m) == 0 ? "" : " not", m);
}

int main(void) {
  test("100",3);
  test("123456",3);
  test("100",15);
  test("105",15);
  // Make big numbers
  char buffer[1001+1];
  sprintf(buffer, "1%01000d", 0);
  test(buffer,15);
  sprintf(buffer, "1%0999d5", 0);
  test(buffer,15);
}
```

Output

```
100 is not divisible by 3
123456 is divisible by 3
100 is not divisible by 15
105 is divisible by 15
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 is not divisible by 15
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005 is divisible by 15
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some "BigInt" library
like https://gmplib.org/ just googling "BigInt C library" will give a lot of examples.
According to the task as you said it... most probably it indeed was especially composed in such a way that you have not to look for a straightforward answer but cheat somehow